# DIY Grout / Caulk

Tags: bathroom, tile, grout, caulking

I have my adult son living in my basement. He noticed water dripping about a month ago, then it stopped. A month later he noticed it again. My son in law suggested it may be from the missing caulking around the tub - in the bathroom right above it.

I called someone in to look at it and have not allowed anyone to use that shower since (this past Sunday, 10/30/16. The regular tile guy was away but suggested we could handle this ourselves and sent me step by step instructions. Not feeling confident enough to tackle the full project, we decided to do the prep work and have my reliable handyman apply the new grout / caulk.

Here's where the problem starts. It was not just a matter of cleaning up the old caulking. After my son in law was cleaned the mold off the caulking around the tub, that's when you could see there were actual chunks of grout missing as well. I asked my son in law to remove any loose grout around it. That's where we are at right now. But here are my dilemmas:

1-In removing the grout, he made a small chip in one of my tiles that needs to be patched so I am looking for a product to repair it.

2-My daughter first told me the need for this repair (new caulking) back in the Spring - April / May. I tried to get someone in but 2 people were not available, life got busy and I neglected to follow up until just now when my son moved in basement and noticed leak. Realizing that I could have had a drip for the past 6 + months, I am MOST concerned by what is going on behind the tiled walls in this bathroom.

Under this bathroom, in the basement below, we only tacked up ceiling panels in this area, so we could access this area (where the pipes are) if need be. I want to try and look up there first to see if we can tell how wet this area is, if we can even see that! How will I know if mold is present? If this has been going on for 6 + mo (that I know of!) do you think I need to consider redoing the tiled walls around the tub or is that extreme? I just don't want to re-grout & caulk only to find out I have a mold problem going on back there.
Please advise. Thank you, LBeth

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Your first dilemma, looking for a product, is unfortunately off-topic for this site. You are better off asking "how should I handle this?".

Comment: My recommendation is to take a few picture from below with the ceiling panels removed and post them here.

Comment: @LBeth Welcome! As mentioned above please post some pictures of the project! Once we know what you are working with we can do our best to assist you :)